# nodejs: action need to be done before requests are handled

Tags: node.js

My app needs to do some action first (and once) and only then start handling the requests and run other actions.
I'm looking for some middleware that will get the first action and a bunch of handlers. It should first will invoke the action, and only when it's done it will call all the handlers without calling the first action again.

Edit: suppose my first action takes a while. I can register the app.get handlers in my first action's callback, but then any request arriving before my first action is done will be lost. Instead, I want to store the requests in a queue until the first action finishes, and only then call the handlers on the pending request. Afterwards, I want my middleware to delete itself, so that only the request handlers will handle the new requests.

Do you know such a middleware?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 0):

Emm... Not sure if I understood you correctly, but...

```
var done = false;
function myFunc () {
   if (done==true)break;
   //your code
   console.log('First');
   //your code
   done=true;
}

app.get('/desk/settings', myFunc, function(req, res) { 
   console.log('Second');
});
```

Reuest -> Middleware myFunc --> request code.

Not what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks, not so much, since I have to pass myFunc to each request handler, right?

Comment: well, actually yes. Everytime '/desk/settings' is called, your middleware wiil be invoked...

Comment: so, I'm looking for a solution that will not require me to pass myFunc to each request handler. I want the middleware to call myFunc once and then I only want the request handlers to be invoked.

Comment: edited my code a bit. I know,it's a so-so solution, but it should work. ('break' wiil not actually work, use return instead of)

Comment: thanks, but I don't really want to call myFunc from each handler (I have many app.get handlers, I'm looking for something more generic).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own middleware like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('first');
  if (firstIsReady) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/error')
  }
})
```

Make sure you put it before the `app.router`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: well suppose I have 2 handlers: app.get('/',...) and app.get('/account'). Now I want the action to be invoked one time before both handlers, and then I don't want it to be invoked at all...after it was invoked once, I only want the appropriate handler to be invoked..